# Designing the Custom page for the product inner page

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, design

I am new to Magento CMS and I am stuck in designing the custom product page according to the design given to me.

[image]
Can anyone say me where to design this actual layout to be done exactly. I have refereed some of the links where it say to be done the layout.xml of the custom theme. But I fear to do this. Please help me someone to achieve this.

Comment: inorder to do this you should learn basics of magento theming.

Comment: @Bilal. I have a doubt can we create the custom CMS  page call the product title,price and add to cart functionality??

Comment: You could add products from a certain category using the following in your cms page editor:

{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_cms" category_id="about us products ID" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}

You could then add a category for the cms page products, for example - create category "about us products" and then add that category id to the widget code.

This way you can easily manage cms displayed products from the category section, rather than hardcoding individual product IDs.

Comment: @Bilal has you can see the design there is only individual product to be displayed. So what way can I call individual product ID?

Comment: From the  look i can say that  this is magento's product detail page... yo don't have to do anything . magento has default functionality for it... magento displays single product on product detail page

Comment: just customize product detail page.. you will get what you are looking for

Comment: @Bilal Thank you so much. Let me try your option, and get back to u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the bellow steps to create a custom product page layout:

- create a new custom theme named like custom product page
- add local.xml in layout folder and set layout for
  "catalog_product_view".
- just copy and Add view.phtml in template folder
- Customize as per your requirement.
- from backed set choose the theme for particular product.
- save the configuration and reload the page from front end

Refer to this link for more info: http://roysimkes.net/blog/2008/09/how-to-customize-magento-product-page/